# Magento include mobile number field in registration form

Tags: magento, custom-fields

Did anyone know how to call `Phone Numnber` field in registration form, like the one in check out page is having.

Please give me your suggestonions to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best plan would be to relabel the "Fax Number" with "Mobile Number" (Unless you really need the fax number also.

This can be changed via the csv templates found in app/locale//

Personally I would just grep for the word "Fax" and go from there.

Comment: I use 1.7 and see no fax field?